# Connection to postgresql with SSL on through a service in GCP

Tags: postgresql, ssl, google-cloud-platform, postgresql-9.3

I am configuring a feature store called FEAST in GCP. I did all the requires steps and I can create and deploy infrastructure.

Now, I have enabled the SSL for Postgresql and I can connect to Postgres DB directly as I have created the SSL certs(client-cert.pem, client-key.pem and server-ca.pem). But, doing the exact process to generate and deploy infrastructure with the feast apply is throwing an error.

The error says ""psycopg2.OperationalError: connection to server at "xx.xxx.xx.x", port 0000 failed: FATAL:  connection requires a valid client certificate
connection to server at "xx.xxx.xx.x", port 0000 failed: FATAL:  pg_hba.conf rejects connection for host "xx.xxx.xx.x", user "postgres", database "postgres", SSL off ""

Any help and advice is much appreciated!!

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: Postgres 9.3 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Comment: Is 0000 a result of your censorship?  That does not look realistic for a port.  What client is connecting?  Is FEAST its own client? Is it libpq based? What did the server's log file say?

Comment: The port is 5432. Feast is a feature store for training and deploying features in ML.